# Does kubernetes support non distributed applications?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

Our store applications are not distributed applications. We deploy on each node and then configured to store specific details. So, it is tightly coupled to node. Can I use kubernetes for this test case? Would I get benefits from it?

Answer (score 1):

> Our store applications are not distributed applications. We deploy on each node and then configured to store specific details. So, it is tightly coupled to node. Can I use kubernetes for this test case?

Based on only this information, it is hard to tell. But Kubernetes is designed so that it should be easy to migrate existing applications. E.g. you can use a `PersistentVolumeClaim` for the directories that your application store information.

That said, it will probably be challenging. A cluster administrator want to treat the Nodes in the cluster as ["cattles"](https://joachim8675309.medium.com/devops-concepts-pets-vs-cattle-2380b5aab313) and throw them away when its time to upgrade. If your app only has one instance, it will have some downtime and your `PersistentVolume` should be backed by a storage system over the network - otherwise the data will be lost when the node is thrown away.

If you want to run more than one instance for *fault tolerance*, it need to be *stateless* - but it is likely not stateless if it stores local data on disk.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to have applications running on fixed nodes of the cluster. It really depends on how those applications behave and why do they need to run on a fixed node of the cluster.

Usually such applications are Stateful and may require interacting with a specific node's resources, or writing directly on a mounted volume on specific nodes for performance reasons and so on.

It can be obtained with a simple nodeSelector or with affinity to nodes ( https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/assign-pod-node/ )

Or with local persistent volumes ( https://kubernetes.io/blog/2019/04/04/kubernetes-1.14-local-persistent-volumes-ga/ )

---

With this said, if all the applications that needs to be executed on the Kubernetes cluster are apps that needs to run on a single node, you lose a lot of benefits as Kubernetes works really well with stateless applications, which may be moved between nodes to obtain high availability and a strong resilience to nodes failure.

The thing is that Kubernetes is complex and brings you a lot of tools to work with, but if you end up using a small amount of them, I think it's an overkill.

I would weight the benefits you could get with adopting Kubernetes (easy way to check the whole cluster health, easy monitoring of logs, metrics and resources usage. Strong resilience to node failure for stateless applications, load balancing of requests and a lot more) with the cons and complexity that it may brings (especially migrating to it can require a good amount of effort, if you weren't using containers to host your applications and so on)